# How do I set a cookie for Jquery sortable grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to set a cookie for the Jquery sortable in a grid layout. 
This is [the sortable grid](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid)

I tried using the Jquery cookie plugin as explained [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie)

I downloaded the plugin and replaced the example code:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            cookie: {
                // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
                expires: 1
            }
        });
    });
```

With this one:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
            cookie: {
                // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
                expires: 1
            }
        });
    });
```

It did not work..Is the cookie example a basic use example and not complete? What else can I try?

Comment: Sortables do not have a cookie option, that's why it's not working ;-). You need to write that by yourself in the "create" and "update" methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.sortable does not support cookies directly. Look under the options tab at the site.
Tabs has a cookie option, sortable does not.

Try looking here:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-sortable-and-save-to-cookie

and here:

http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/

There is something about using cookies with .sortable.

If not, then try googling, there seems to be a lot of hits for it, so there should be something useful out there.
Best of luck with it.